# C# web browser tab text

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello i have been creating a web browser for college. The problem that i have that is driving me insane is trying to get current web browser page i am ons text in the tab like if i am on Google i would like to say it in the tab.

i tried

```
private void addTextImageTab()
    {
        try
        {
            mainBrowserTC.SelectedTab.Text = getCurrentWB().Document.Url.ToString();
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }


    }
```

and my getCurrentWB() method is

```
private WebBrowser getCurrentWB()
    {
        return (WebBrowser)mainBrowserTC.SelectedTab.Controls[0];
    }
```

Every time i try to run it it crashes i tried every thing that i know and search the web the last few days and could find a solution please help.

Comment: What error do you get? Did you check to see if there are valid controls in the SelectedTab? What EXACTLY are you trying to do?

Comment: Thnaks you Ahmed for your time .Its dose not even give a error, it tries to load form and then just suddenly stops and goes back to the code with no errors that is what i dont understand